# Are Coco and Jellal (aka Mystogan) siblings?

Tags: fairy-tail

In the anime, it is hinted that Coco is the daughter of the king, but she does not seem like one, nor does anyone refer to her as one. Jellal (known as Mystogan in Earth Land) on the other hand is clearly the son and a prince and is more than a dozen times called prince. So that would make them siblings, but they don't act like they are siblings at all.

Are Coco and Jellal siblings? If so, why don't they act like it, and how come Coco doesn't appear to be a princess?

Comment: Based on what I recollect, I thought Coco was a messenger. When was it hinted that she was the daughter of the king?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coco and Jellal are not siblings. According to http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Coco, Coco is the Assistant Chief of Staff and she also serves as a messenger. The wiki page lists no relatives. She has a high standing in the royal court, but she is not a princess.

Answer (score 0):

In the anime, Virgo called Lucy a princess so then you could hear Coco say "so she's a princess *too*", so it might be possible.

Comment: Welcome to [anime.se]. Could you mention the related episode to back up this answer?